How to add Common C++ Code inside a Flutter Plugin so that it's available to both iOS and Android Environments?
I have a flutter plugin (lets call is FPlugin) which majorly works with C++ code.
The flow is like this -
Flutter App -> Flutter Plugin -> Calls C++ code via DartFFI
This project was initially meant for Android environment and they used CMake, etc to make all the C++ files available in scope by putting it directly inside /android folder INSIDE the plugin. Now I'm migrating it to iOS as well and I don't want to copy all this code in iOS folder. It should be a common place like /cpp alongside /android and /ios.
How can I acheive this? What changes should I make in Xcode or iOS Podspec inside the plugin so that the iOS environment also has access to these files along with Android?
Follow up - This C++ code is using third party libraries as well like boost, how can I add that as a dependency inside the plugin as well?
Note- There is no involvement of Obj-C here. The Flutter entry point of the plugin directly calls C++ functions which in turn may use Boost header files.
Putting all the cpp code inside iOS/Classes didn't help.
I changed ios/FPlugin.podspec looks like this -
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'uac'
  s.version          = '0.0.1'
  s.summary          = 'A new flutter plugin project.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
A new flutter plugin project.
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = 'http://example.com'
  s.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Your Company' => 'email@example.com' }
  s.source           = { :path => '.' }
  s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*.{h,m,mm,cpp,hpp}', 'Classes/cots/**/*.{h,cpp,hpp}'
  s.dependency 'Flutter'
  s.platform = :ios, '8.0'

  # Flutter.framework does not contain a i386 slice.
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 
    'CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY' => 'libc++',
    'CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD' => 'c++14',
    'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES', 
    'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'i386' 
  }
  s.swift_version = '5.0'
end```

The cots folder where my boost library is. I was trying to include that as well but failed. It kept giving me pod install fails or 'Multiple Commands Produce' Errors

